# Serialization of dynamic created WPF window to XAML fails

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm working with VS 2013, WPF and C# on a dynamic maskdesigner for WPF-masks.
Because i'm not familiar with that stuff i have programmed a small WPF-application for making some experiments.
While These experiments i have encountered the following problems:

1. Serialization of the Canvas Panel to XAML fails, when a control like a DataGrid is binded to a datasource.
2. Even if the serialization works, i cannot see the bindings in XAML.

In my application i got a ViewModel-class in which i'm creating a DataTable with two columns ("vorname" and "nachname") and four rows.
Further i got a DataView-property which returns the DefaultView-property of the DataTable.
First i create a DataGrid in code-behind:

```
private void CreateDatagrid()
{
    DataGrid datagrid = new DataGrid();
    datagrid.Name = "datagrid";

    datagrid.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 20.0);
    datagrid.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 10.0);
    datagrid.SetValue(DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumnsProperty, true);

    //datagrid.ItemsSource = DataSource;

    _canvasPanel.Children.Add(datagrid);
}
```

As You can see, the line in which the ItemsSource of the DataGrid will be set is commented at this point of time.
Next i'm creating two TextBoxes which will be binded to the actual selected row in the DataGrid and to a special column in that row.

```
private void CreateTextboxes()
{
    CreateTextbox("vorname", "datagrid", "SelectedItem.vorname", 220, 10);
    CreateTextbox("nachname", "datagrid", "SelectedItem.nachname", 220, 40);
}

private void CreateTextbox(string name, string elementName, string path, double leftPos, double topPos)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, leftPos);
    tb.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, topPos);
    tb.Width = 150;
    tb.Name = name;
    Binding tbbinding = new Binding();
    tbbinding.ElementName = elementName;
    tb.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, tbbinding);
    _canvasPanel.Children.Add(tb);
}
```

As You can see the Textboxes "vorname" and "nachname" are created and binded to the their namesakes in the DataGrid-columns.
Then i want to serialize the parent control (including it's child controls) as a xaml-file.
In that case i push a Button which does the follwing:

```
public void SerializeToXaml(FrameworkElement parentControl)
{
    FileStream fs = File.Open("MyXamlFile.xaml", FileMode.Create);
    XamlWriter.Save(parentControl, fs);
    fs.Close();
}
```

Without binding the ItemsSource to the DataView it works.
At this point i'm just a little bit disturbed by the fact, that the bindings seem not be serialized in the XAML file .
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
<Canvas Background="#FFF0F8FF" Name="designerpanel" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="datagrid" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="10">
<DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
<BindingGroup Name="{x:Null}" NotifyOnValidationError="False" ValidatesOnNotifyDataError="True" SharesProposedValues="True" />
</DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
</DataGrid>
<TextBox Name="vorname" Width="150" Canvas.Left="220" Canvas.Top="10" xml:space="preserve" />
<TextBox Name="nachname" Width="150" Canvas.Left="220" Canvas.Top="40" xml:space="preserve" />
</Canvas>
```

But when i bind the ItemsSource-property to the DataView it fails - as You can see below in the error message.

```
System.InvalidOperationException wurde nicht behandelt.
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The not public type "MS.Internal.NamedObject" cannot be serialized.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.Primitives.MarkupWriter.VerifyTypeIsSerializable(Type type)
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Bye,
Patrick

Comment: Do you have a type somewhere that is internal?  That seems to be what it is indicating to be the problem.  You can only serialize public types

Comment: I have found an article on SocialMSDN in which they say, that the NewItemPlaceHolder of the DataGrid is a non-public object and cannot be serialized.
When i set the property CanUserAddRows to false, the serialization works.
But this is a little bit curious and i cannot see the binding Information in the XAML file which is created by the serialization.